# How can i get the players into a datagridview

Tags: c#

```
?xml version='1.0'?>
<!-- This file contains data on major league baseball players.-->
<Major_League_Baseball>
  <player>
    <name>A. J. Pierzynski</name>
    <team>White Sox</team>
    <atBats>479</atBats>
    <hits>133</hits>
  </player>
  <player>
    <name>Aaron Hill</name>
    <team>Diamondbacks</team>
    <atBats>609</atBats>
    <hits>184</hits>
  </player>
  <player>
    <name>Adam Dunn</name>
    <team>White Sox</team>
    <atBats>539</atBats>
    <hits>110</hits>
  </player>
  <player>
    <name>Adam Jones</name>
    <team>Orioles</team>
    <atBats>648</atBats>
    <hits>186</hits>
  </player>
</Major_League_Baseball>
```

Given the xml doc above and a listbox that has all the team names listed, how could I pull the player name into a datagridview on the condition that the listbox selected item is equal to the team name?

Comment: do a google search on how to bind XML to a DataGridView would be my first thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("team", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("atBats", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("hits", typeof(int));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach(XElement play in doc.Descendants("player"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    (string)play.Element("name"),
                    (string)play.Element("team"),
                    (int)play.Element("atBats"),
                    (int)play.Element("hits")
                });
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```